# How to force Jackson to invoke Set methods of all attributes in object (dto) in controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I have some validations in my "command", parameter of the controller that are executed within the set of each attribute, the problem is that the attributes not informed, jackson does not invoke the set method to do the validation. Is it possible to force Jackson to invoke the Set method even when the attribute is missing?

For exemple Payload without agency field:

```
{
   "bank": "237",
   "account": "20772-1",
   "taxId": "36456155800",
   "paidAmount": 30.00
}
```

My Controller:

```
public Return confirmTransfer(@RequestBody RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand command) {
    System.out.println(command);
}
```

Class Java:

```
public class RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand {

    public static final String ERR_INVALID_AGENCY = "Agency number can not be null.";

    private String bank;
    private String account;
    private String agency;
    private String taxId;

    public RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand(BigDecimal paidAmount, String bank, String account,
            String agency, String taxId) {

        setPaidAmount(paidAmount);
        setBank(bank);
        setAccount(account);
        setAgency(agency);
        setTaxId(taxId);
    }

    public void setRechargeId(RechargeId rechargeId) {
        assertArgumentNotNull(rechargeId, Recharge.ERR_RECHARGE_ID_INVALID);
        this.rechargeId = rechargeId;
    }

    private void setPaidAmount(BigDecimal paidAmount) {
        if (paidAmount == null || paidAmount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(Recharge.ERR_INVALID_AMOUNT);
        this.paidAmount = paidAmount;
    }

    private void setBank(String bank) {
        assertArgumentNotEmpty(bank, TransferInformation.ERR_INVALID_BANK_NUMBER);
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    private void setAccount(String account) {
        assertArgumentNotEmpty(account, TransferInformation.ERR_INVALID_ACCOUNT);
        this.account = account;
    }

    private void setAgency(String agency) {
        assertArgumentNotEmpty(agency, ERR_INVALID_AGENCY);
        this.agency = agency;
    }

    private void setTaxId(String taxId) {
        assertArgumentNotEmpty(taxId, ERR_INVALID_TAX_ID);
        this.taxId = taxId;
    }

}
```

In this case, for each field the set method is invoked to do the validation, except the agency field that was not informed in the payload, it should soon throw the exception contained in the method assertArgumentNotEmpty.

Comment: why not use the `@NotNull` and `@Min` annotations to deal with validations?

Comment: Because using this annotation the return object for the client is specific to the framework, I need a custom return. This my exception i can capture in @ControllerAdvice class and return a friendlier response.

Comment: if your javax validation failed then you can intercept @ControllerAdvice. Even in javax validation you can use message where pass validation failed message

Answer (score 1):

yes jackson will not invoke the `setter` methods of fields that are not passed in payload, if you want to validate missing fields you need custom `Deserializer`

```
class RechargeTransferConfirmationCommandDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand> {

@Override
public RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand responseModel = jp.readValueAs(RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand.class);

    RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand finalModel = new RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand();
    finalModel.set agency(responseModel. agency == null || age.trim().isEmpty() ? "agency" : responseModel.agency);

    return finalModel;
   }

}
```

And you model should be

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DefaultModelDeserializer.class)
public class DefaultModel {

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `@JsonSetter` in method && declare `no args constructor` also:

```
public RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand(){
}
@JsonSetter
    public void setRechargeId(RechargeId rechargeId) {
        assertArgumentNotNull(rechargeId, Recharge.ERR_RECHARGE_ID_INVALID);
        this.rechargeId = rechargeId;
    }
```

But better you use javax validation. Look at [*this*](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) to get details.

Another way:
You can write all validtion in one method and use @AssertTrue:

```
@AssertTrue
public boolean isValid(){
//if all field is valid then return true;
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved using @JsonCreator, thank you all for your help

```
@JsonCreator
public RechargeTransferConfirmationCommand(@JsonProperty("paidAmount") BigDecimal paidAmount,
        @JsonProperty("bank") String bank, @JsonProperty("account") String account,
        @JsonProperty("agency") String agency, @JsonProperty("taxId") String taxId) {

    setPaidAmount(paidAmount);
    setBank(bank);
    setAccount(account);
    setAgency(agency);
    setTaxId(taxId);
}
```